# Cannot Convert form 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSQLQuery<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<long> to 'long'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having trouble adding a variable I am populating via a sql query to a list.

```
List<long> TillsTotal = new List<long>();

string tillquery = string.Format("select Sum(Value) from valuemetrics where custid='{0} '
                                  and metricname={1} ' and date>='{2}' and date<='{3}' and tillno={4}",
                                  Cust, Metric, FromDate , ToDate, till);
var tillValue = item.Database.SqlQuery<IEnumerable<long>>(tillquery);
TillsTotal.Add(tillValue);
```

I get the error

> Cannot Convert form `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSQLQuery<System.Collections.Generic.Ienumerable<long>` to `long`

on the the last line where I am trying to add the result to the list

Note: the query I am running returns a single value of a number

Comment: @cathal-o-donnell Try TillsTotal.AddRange(tillValue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible, but you can try this:

```
List<long> TillsTotal = new List<long>();

string tillquery = string.Format("select Sum(Value) from valuemetrics where custid='{0} '
                              and metricname={1} ' and date>='{2}' and date<='{3}' and tillno={4}",
                              Cust, Metric, FromDate , ToDate, till);
var tillValue = item.Database.SqlQuery<IEnumerable<long>>(tillquery).ToList();
TillsTotal.Add(tillValue.First());
```

`tillValue` is always a list, nevertheless if your query returns single value or multiple.

Answer (score 4):

[`Database.SqlQuery<T>()` returns a `DbRawSqlQuery<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery%60%601%28System.String,System.Object[]%29), which only executes the query when you enumerate the results.

You also can't add an `IEnumerable<T>` to a `List<T>` through `Add()` (you could through `AddRange()`).

So to fix both at once:

```
var tillsTotal = await tillValue.ToListAsync();
```

Or, to use non-async LINQ code:

```
var tillsTotal = tillValue.ToList();
```

If you're certain that this is a scalar function, since you have no grouping, you can also use `Single()`:

```
var thisTotal = tillValue.Single();
tillsTotal.Add(thisTotal);
```